# Find a, b, c in the polynom P(x)=ax^2+bx+c if P(x+1)+P(-1)=8x^2+6x+10

Tags: polynomials

I've tried to put if P(u)=8(x-1)^2-6(x-1)+10+8(u+1)^2-6(u+1)+10.
How should I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By hypothesis we have

$$a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)+c+a(x-1)^2+b(x-1)+c\\=2ax^2+2bx+(2a+2b+2c)=8x^2+6x+10$$
so

$$2a=10,\quad 2b=6,\quad 2a+2b+2c=10\implies a=\cdots,b=\cdots,c=\cdots$$

Comment: I've made a change because I had written it wrong: Find a, b, c in the polynom P(x)=ax^2+bx+c if P(x+1)+P(x-1)=8x^2+6x+10